# Regex two digit pairing

Tags: regex

I have the following regex I use to find numeric pairs; `[0-9][0-9]`

If the string is even length, I get exactly what I want.

```
string x ="1234";
Regex.Matches(enc, @"[0-9][0-9]")
```

With the regex I get `12`,`34`.

if I have `string x="12345"` I get `12`,`34`.  How do I modify this if I want `23`,`45`?

Comment: Why not just reverse your string and then re-reverse the result?

Comment: Just use `"[0-9][0-9]$"` to match 2 numbers at the end of the string

Comment: So you want to not capture the first number of odd lengths?

Comment: You could do some kind of mod(string) % 2 = 0 to see if it's even, if not ltrim the first character?

Comment: It doesn't sound like a work for regex, iterate the string (char by char) and when string[i] and string[i+1] are both digits, add that substring to the result-set. You can start iterating from the second index if you don't want the first result.

Comment: yes, I want to not capture the first number of odd lengths.  The example I gave is overly simple.

If I have a string of 12345[FNC1]00112233, I want to capture 23,45, 00,11,22,33 

if I have a string of 12345[FNC1]0011223, I want to capture 23,45,00,11,22.

Comment: For odd-length numbers just use `^(?:\d{2})+\d$` use `^(?:\d{2})+$` for even-length numbers. What's the purpose of the program?

Comment: What are you exactly grabbing; all two number pairs in a string, the last two number pairs ...?

Comment: @DavidGerst in the strings you put in your comment, why does `12345[FNC1]0011223` match `00, 11, 22` instead of `01, 12, 23` as your logic says it should?

Comment: sorry for being confusing.  my regex doesn't currently capture what I said, but rather that is what I'm working towards.  I got stuck on paring off the odd length 12345 as 23 45.

Comment: You can use `\d{2}(?=(?:\d{2})+\b|\b)` or `\d{2}(?=(?:\d{2})+\[|\[)|\d{2}(?=\d*$)` assuming the resultset you put in your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do it like this:

`([0-9]{2})+$`

This will match all the pairs, unless you have an odd number of digits, in which case you'll match everything except the first digit. If you need the separate pairs, you can then just split the returned match into sequential pairs.

Live example: https://regex101.com/r/3gNoQd/4

Answer (score 2):

### Brief

This answer uses the input you entered in a comment below your question (see *Results* section for the inputs)

---

### Code

Since I'm not certain exactly what the outputs should be, I'll present you with the following 3 methods.

#### Method 1

This method always ensures the pairs are matched from the end of the string.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/CqJfZ6/1)

```
\d{2}(?=(?:(?:\d{2})+|)(?:\D|$))
```

#### Method 2

This method always ensures the pairs are matched from the end of the string only when a specific token follows the numbers

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/CqJfZ6/2)

```
\d{2}(?=(?:\d{2})+\[|\[)
```

#### Method 3

This method always ensures the pairs are matched from the end of the string only when a specific token follows the numbers and matches the remaining numbers normally (but also in pairs)

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/CqJfZ6/3)

```
\d{2}(?=(?:\d{2})+\[|\[)|\d{2}(?=\d*$)
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
12345[FNC1]00112233
12345[FNC1]0011223
```

#### Output

**Method 1**

```
23 45 00 11 22 33
23 45 01 12 23
```

**Method 2**

```
23 45
23 45
```

**Method 3**

```
23 45 00 11 22 33
23 45 00 11 22
```

---

### Explanation

#### Method 1

- `\d{2}` Match any digit exactly twice
- `(?=(?:\d{2})+\b|\b)` Positive lookahead ensuring either of the following matches

  - `(?:\d{2})+\b` Match the following

    - `(?:\d{2})+` Match the following one or more times

      - `\d{2}` Match any digit exactly twice
    - `\b` Assert the position as a word boundary
  - `\b` Assert the position as a word boundary

#### Method 2

Same as *Method 1*'s explanation, but instead of using `\b`, it uses `\[` to assert that the following character matches `[` literally.

#### Method 3

Same as *Method 2*'s explanation, but adds `|\d{2}(?=\d*$)` to the end.

- `|` acts like a boolean OR (match *Method 2* or the following)
- `\d{2}` Match any digit exactly twice
- `(?=\d*$)` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows matches

  - `\d*` Match any digit any number of times
  - `$` Assert position at the end of the line